# MongoDB stuck by too much data

Tags: javascript, json, database, mongodb, express

I recently joined a project where MongoDB is used to store images as base64 strings, and the file size limit is set to 50MB. I have no rational explanation as to why it is like that. I've encountered an issue where two exceptionally large images have been submitted, causing MongoDB to get stuck when attempting to fetch them. These problematic records are preventing me from reading their IDs, making it difficult to directly address them.

How can I resolve this issue without having to drop the entire table?

If there is a way to retreive the IDs of the records I would be able to only delete them.

Comment: Maybe you can create an index that contains the _id and the fields that you use to identify the documents. Then you can run a [covered query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) that uses only the index and does not load the documents themselves to retrieve the ids.

Comment: It worked on MongoDB compass with the `{ _id: 1 }` in the project field in the options submenu. Thank you! You can post this as a working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid loading the complete document just for identifying the `_id`, you can use a [Covered Query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) that uses only data that is stored in an index:

1. Create an index that contains the fields that you need to identify the documents and the `_id` field.
2. Run a query that filters the documents by the fields in the index and make sure that only the `_id` field is returned by using a projection: `{ _id: 1 }`

This way, MongoDB does not need to load the huge document from the collection but uses only the index in memory.